# Can i open and edit reStructedText (.RST) files with Blender?

Tags: documentation

I write my own documentation for personal use in learning Blender. I use reStructedText and Sphinx. This is plain text in RST files.
I used to work in a Blender text editor (and i like it). **Is it possible to open and edit RST files in a Blender text editor?** At the moment, RST files are not open (but TXT open), and renaming to TXT is inconvenient (sorry for my English).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender can open any text file in its text editor. The file browser will not show the .rst files if you have filtering turned on, click the little funnel icon to turn filtering on/off.

[image: filtering icons]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm complicating. Configured conf.py in source folder of my documentation:

```
    source_suffix = {
'.rst': 'restructuredtext',
'.txt': 'restructuredtext',
}
```

**I added TXT suffix in conf.py, and renamed all files from .RST to .TXT**